# What are the number of favourable outcomes for this probability problem?

Tags: probability

I cannot figure out how to do this problem.

Given 20 people, what is the probability that among the 12 months in the year, there are 4 months containing exactly 2 birthdays, and 4 containing exactly 3 birthdays?

I understand that all possible outcomes are $12^{20}$.
I’m trying to think of each person as $P_1, P_2...$ etc and allot them months accordingly but, if I want to allot, say January to Person 1, how is that feasible? It doesn’t make sense to me, I know this is wrong.
Please give me a hint / help out.

Comment: Are we to assume that births are equally distributed over the 12 months? (Seems unrealistic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influence_of_seasonal_birth_in_humans)

Answer (score 1):

You begin to choose the months:

- There are $\dbinom{12}{4}$ choices for the month where there will be two birthday (let's call them $A_1$,$A_2$,$A_3$ and $A_4$)
- There are $\dbinom{8}{4}$ choices left to chose the month where there are three birthdays ($B_1$,$B_2$,...)

Then you choose in which month you put everyone:

- You choose $\dbinom{20}{2}$ people to be in $A_1$, $\dbinom{18}{2}$ to be in $A_2$ and so on for $A_3$ and $A_4$. And finnaly $\dbinom{12}{3}$ for $B_1$,...

The last etape can be written with miltinomial coefficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

$\dbinom{20}{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3}$

Overall the number of choice is $\dbinom{12}{4}\dbinom{8}{4}\dbinom{20}{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3}$

Let me know if you find errors

Comment: I understand this fully. Now I’m getting 0.0010604 as the answer. But that doesn’t match the answer given in my text book. Which is 0.01697.

Comment: There should be an error somwhere...Let me think about it again.

Comment: The ration 0.0010604/0.01697 is an approximation 16, we have to figure out why there is this gap. Moreover I find a first error, I took $\dbinom{12}{4}$ choices for month for the A's. But since we give them names we have to multiple by $4!$. The same for the second choice. Now we have $(4!)^2=576$ which is more than 16. We have to divide by $(3!)^2$